# JavaScript select first n booleans

Tags: javascript, highcharts, boolean

I don't know exactly how to title my questions, but let me explain my scenario:

I have a chart with 6 series of data and I want to display only the first 3 that are not `0`. So i have something like:

```
if(a == 0) showA = false;
if(b == 0) showB = false;
if(c == 0) showC = false;
if(d == 0) showD = false;
if(e == 0) showE = false;
if(f == 0) showF = false;
```

The above is checking to see which series have data and hides those that are empty. However, if they all have data, all 6 will be visible in the chart.

What I would like is to select only the first 3 `showX` that are `true` and mark the others `false` so they don't show up on chart.

I was thinking I can push the `booleans` to an array and take only the first 3 that are `true`, but as each series has it's own `visibility variable`, how would I mark the others as `false`?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: First thing to do is putting them in an array, instead of using 6 different variables. Not only the `showA`, `showB`, `show…` ones, but right the `a`, `b`, `…` ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a counter in your if-clauses. Count each instance of `true` and set it to `false` when a certain amount of charts (3) has been reached.

Code example:

```
var max = 3;
var counter = 0;
showA = a != 0 && counter++ < max;
showB = b != 0 && counter++ < max;
showC = c != 0 && counter++ < max;
showD = d != 0 && counter++ < max;
showE = e != 0 && counter++ < max;
showF = f != 0 && counter++ < max;
```

The reason the counter is only incremented when the value != 0 is because JavaScript has [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

This could be made even more scalable by using arrays.

```
var values = [a, b, c, d, e, f];
var shouldBeVisible = new Array(values.length);

var counter = 0;
var max = 3;
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    shouldBeVisible[i] = values[i] != 0 && counter++ < max;
}
```